# Python UNICODE csv reader GZIPPED file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode, gzip

I have read every thread related to unicode reading, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Im trying to read a csv which happens to have a utf-8 BOM signature on it and is also utf-8.

So, after opening the file, reading it with unicodecsv library, I've tried different things.

```
def _extract_gz(self):  # fd
    logging.info("Gz detected")
    self.fp = gzip.open(self.path)
    return unicodecsv.reader(self.path.read().decode('utf-8-sig').splitlines(), encoding='utf-8')
```

Still fails at row 226. UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 226: ordinal not in range(128)

Also tried this approach but failed as well.

```
def _extract_gz(self):  # fd
    logging.info("Gz detected")
    self.fp = gzip.open(self.path)
    self.f = self.unicode_csv_reader()
    return self.f

def unicode_csv_reader(self):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(self.fp.read().decode('utf-8-sig').splitlines())
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [cell.encode('utf-8', 'replace') for cell in row]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks everyone.

Version is *Python 2.7.12*

Comment: I am aware that unicodecsv must be bytearray. I also tried this approach:

 `code` def _extract_gz(self):  # fd
  logging.info("Gz detected")
  self.fp = gzip.open(self.path)
  self.f = unicodecsv.reader(bytearray(self.fp.read())
  return self.f

It seems to format it all correctly but then, as soon as i do f.next() to read the header, this error comes up.

TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, int found

even though printing type(f) returns unicodecsv.py2.UnicodeReader

Comment: If you are using CSV and having UTF issues, better put python-2 or python-3 tag, as I recall different (and tricky) behaviour differences.

Comment: Thanks for the response @MariusSiuram, which tags do you mean?

Comment: I was referring to the StackOverflow tags on your question. In addition, you can edit (can you?) to specify your exact python version.

Comment: Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `csv` module does not support Unicode (assuming Python 2.x), but there is a drop-in replacement `unicodecsv` module which does (and which you've  apparently tried, unsuccessfully) and it should be fairly straightforward:

```
import gzip
import unicodecsv as csv

def read_csv(filename, has_bom=True, **kwargs):
    with gzip.open(filename, "r") as f:
        if has_bom:
            f.seek(3)  # skip the BOM
        reader = csv.reader(f, **kwargs)
        for row in reader:
            yield row

for row in read_csv("path/to/your.csv.gz", delimiter=";"):  # encoding needed for BOM
    print(row)  # or do whatever you want with it
```

Should do the trick.

**UPDATE** - The above code works with your uploaded file and doesn't throw any errors (since your files are delimited by a semi-column I've added that as well), however there is a bug in the `unicodecsv` module - it doesn't remove quotes around the first column name when parsing a file with BOM so I've updated the code to reflect that.

When running it on your uploaded file you get the following output (YMMV, depends how your console prints unicode):

```
[u'Name', u'Ref', u'POS', u'POS', u'Status', u'City', u'']
[u'Hotel Flamero', u'3365', u'ES', u'0.27', u'No Change', u'Matalascañas', u'']
```

(the last empty entry is due to your CSV having the last entry as empty)

**UPDATE#2** - Don't have a MySQL instance at hand, but you can check that it parses just fine using an in-memory SQLite DB:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")  # create an in-memory DB
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE test (Name TEXT, Ref TEXT, POS TEXT, Status TEXT, City TEXT)")

header = None
for row in read_csv("path/to/your.csv.gz", delimiter=";"):
    del row[-1]  # remove the last element as it's always empty
    if header is None:  # get the header first
        header = row
        continue
    query = u"INSERT INTO test ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
        u", ".join(header),
        u", ".join(u"'{}'".format(column) for column in row)  # quote each column entry
    )
    c.execute(query)

# now lets read our data from the DB
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
for row in c.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

which happily prints:

```
(u'Hotel Flamero', u'3365', u'ES', u'No Change', u'Matalascañas')
```

Comment: If I do that I get "new_row = str(row[0]).replace('"','').split(';')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 224: ordinal not in range(128)"

Maybe its when I convert to str to replace the unwanted characters " in the string? (Let's say that the csv contains strings with double quotes, and I want to remove them, they look like so [ '"name"', etc..]

Comment: @AlbertoC. - can you post a sample of your CSV file? This should work with any normal gzipped CSV (assuming the default quotations, separators etc.) w/ BOM out there.

Comment: @AlbertoC. - don't post it here, upload somewhere a gzipped version of a few rows that causes the aforementioned error with the above code.

Comment: Here you go @zwer: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=52983139705526271159

Comment: Here is where it fails in my code (skipping header, it fails at the first row of the test.csv i sent you).

   for row in f:
    print(row)
    new_row = str(row[0]).replace('"','').split(';')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: If i remove "str" from that line, it all works well, but its not utf-8 encoded. In the mysql db the names still appear like 'Alto AragÃ³n'

Comment: Hi @zwer, thanks for the update. I was removing the BOM myself after looping for every row (after the header). 

Still, when making the inserts in the mysql (the table has utf-8 encoding), it shows the names with unencoded characters. My temrinal prints this:

[u'Name', u'Ref', u'POS', u'POS', u'Status', u'City', u'']
[u'Hotel Flamero', u'3365', u'ES', u'0.27', u'No Change', 'Matalasca\xf1as', u'']. Should be correctly inserted, right?

Comment: I found the problem @zwer. The problem is that the sniffer was not detecting the delimiter correctly, and thus it was encoding as utf-8 the whole block, not each of the variables. ....  Big fail.

Thanks !